# Problem with this C code

Tags: c

I have seen this code on a website and user who posted this code wanted to know about 
the impact of  `fflush(stdin)` in this code. This is code below

```
main()
{
  char *str1="string one";
  char *str2="string two";
  char charbuf; // store characters in buffer

  puts("\nEnter first string");
  gets(str1);
  fflush(stdin);  /*what does this mean here*/

  while( (charbuf=getchar() ) != EOF && charbuf!='\n')
      ; // clear unwanted data

  puts("\nEnter second string");
  gets(str2);
  fflush(stdin);/*what does this mean here*/

  while( (charbuf=getchar() ) != EOF && charbuf!='\n')
      ;

  for(;*str1==*str2&(*str1!='\0'||*str2!='\0\);str1++,str2++) ;
  {
    printf("\nthe string are equal");
  }
  else   
  {
   printf("\nthe string are not equal");
   }
 return;
}
```

But for me before reaching to fflush(stdin) statement programmer already made a big mistake i.e. use of get(str1);

Would it be ok to use gets(str1) here??

Comment: There seems to be an `if(...)` line missing after the `for`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Flushing `stdin` is undefined by the standard](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html) and therefore **wrong**. It is supposed to do that the following `while` does: discard user input until (and including) `\n`.

```
fflush(stdin);/*what does this mean here*/
```

It is never ok to use `gets` since `fgets` is always available and `gets` will be removed from [the next version of the standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X).

> Removal of the gets function, deprecated in the current C language
>   standard revision, ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), in favor of a new
>   safe alternative, gets_s

#### EDIT

Obviously since `str1` and `str2` point to string literals, they are not writable. Writing to them (via `gets` or anything else) is undefined.

Comment: This is not what i asked @cnicutar

Comment: @OP Then why did you ask "what does this mean here" ?

Comment: What i am trying to allude is char *str1 is read only memory location and using gets(str1) does not do any memory violation ?? I am not sure on this and that is what i wanted to confirm!!

Comment: @Amit: exactly, I also mentioned that in my response below.

Comment: Yes @Diedo i read it now and that behavior i wanted to confirm and about the second point i wanted to know more  "gets may be beyond the ending of the string"

Answer (score 4):

First, the `fflush` of the `stdin` causes an undefined behavior (thanks to [Paul R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) for the clarification).

Second, you're right, using `gets` with a variable with an initial value is not correct. First, because the memory pointed by this variable may be just read only (DATA section of your program, that typically include read-only data); second, `gets` may be beyond the ending of the string, causing memory corruption (for instance, overwriting other data stored in the DATA section following that string). Finally, the use of `gets` is deprecated precisely for this reason: you cannot limit the extent of the string read.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking about `fflush(stdin)` which is not valid and results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's still not correct - `fflush(stdin)` does **not** discard input data - it results in **undefined behaviour**. See e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush. You need the non-portable `fpurge` if you want to discard input data, see e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the question, rather than discuss the meaning (or lack thereof) of fflush() on a input stream:

**The use of `gets()` is never correct under any circumstances.**  There is no chance of being able to guarantee to avoid a buffer overflow.

You can use `fgets()` instead as an almost direct and much safer alternative.